# libGDX, RoboVM - how to edit Obj-C code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, libgdx, robovm

I have created a game with libGDX and used RoboVM to run it on iOS and now I would like to add some iOS  specific code to my project. I have read about robopods, but I was wondering if I can just simply open the converted ojective-c code within xcode and just simply edit it just like I did it with Android.

Comment: maybe that's not an option though, cause why would they create all those bindings is I could just add some obj-c code to it..? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can add platform specific code directly into your LibGDX project.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

It seems like a lot of hassle to have to modify the converted code every time you bug fix or update the app.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! My question is actually related to what comes after creating the interfaces. They work on android perfectly, but now I would like to add Admob  & Facebook to my iOS app. on developers.facebook.com for example, there are samples written in objective-c and libgdx works in java. same with google ads.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry I'm not sure about that as I haven't coded anything for iOS yet (only have windows here). However, if you're only needing Admob and Facebook, there is info for setting up Admob on iOS here https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx#ios-setup-robovm and a Facebook Graph extension here https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-facebook so maybe these will help.

Comment: Yes, I have been messing around with these, but did not manage to get it working, so I was asking if there are other ways. But I will keep on trying, it will be fine :)